# Why is my Button Image setGraphic method not being displayed?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the image files in my bin folder but when I run my program all I have is my button options that are not being replaced with my images. I think it has something to do with the file: in front of the images but I'm not sure. The images are not actually a moving gif (dunno why its called gif).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Project4 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        Button btnKings;
        Button btnDucks;
        Button btnSharks;
        Button btnBlues;

        btnKings = new Button("Kings");
        btnDucks = new Button("Ducks");
        btnSharks = new Button("Sharks");
        btnBlues = new Button("Blues");

        Image imgKings = new Image("file:kings.jpg");
        btnKings.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgKings));

        Image imgDucks = new Image("file:ducks.gif");
        btnDucks.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgDucks));

        Image imgSharks = new Image("file:sharks.gif");
        btnSharks.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgSharks));

        Image imgBlues = new Image("file:blues.gif");
        btnBlues.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgBlues));

        HandleButtonClick clickEvent = new HandleButtonClick();
        btnKings.setOnAction(clickEvent);

        btnDucks.setOnAction(new HandleButtonClick("You clicked the ducKS!"));
        btnKings.setOnAction(new HandleButtonClick("You clicked the Kings"));
        btnSharks.setOnAction(new HandleButtonClick("You clicked the sharks"));
        btnBlues.setOnAction(new HandleButtonClick("You clicked the blues"));

        root.getChildren().add(btnKings);
        root.getChildren().add(btnDucks);
        root.getChildren().add(btnSharks);
        root.getChildren().add(btnBlues);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 130);
        primaryStage.setTitle("HockeyButtons");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the images shown? I have tried your code in my case they not shown at all.

Comment: No thats the problem. I cant find out how to replace the words buttons with the pictures

Answer (score 2):

> I cant find out how to replace the words buttons with the pictures
>   **Nghia Duong**

If you want only images to be shown on the button but text then you should create Button without text.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Project4 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        Button btnKings;
        Button btnDucks;
        Button btnSharks;
        Button btnBlues;

        btnKings = new Button();
        btnDucks = new Button();
        btnSharks = new Button();
        btnBlues = new Button();

        Image imgKings = new Image("kings.jpg");
        btnKings.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgKings));

        Image imgDucks = new Image("ducks.gif");
        btnDucks.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgDucks));

        Image imgSharks = new Image("sharks.gif");
        btnSharks.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgSharks));

        Image imgBlues = new Image("blues.gif");
        btnBlues.setGraphic(new ImageView(imgBlues));

        root.getChildren().add(btnKings);
        root.getChildren().add(btnDucks);
        root.getChildren().add(btnSharks);
        root.getChildren().add(btnBlues);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 960, 130);
        primaryStage.setTitle("HockeyButtons");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And here you are showing the path of the image incorrectly.

```
Image imgKings = new Image("file:kings.jpg");
```

You'd better show absolute path or if the images are in classpath folder then by:

```
String absolutePathToIcon =
                getClass().getResource("kings.jpg").toExternalForm();
Image imgKings = new Image(absolutePathToIcon);
```